# Change django admin label position

Tags: django, django-admin

I need to change how the default admin form is rendered.

It shows the label on the left like the image below.
[image]

But I want it to be displayed on top of the input field, any idea?

Here is my `admin.py`

```
class ApplicationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ApplicationAdminForm
    list_display = ['last_name', 'income']

    fieldsets=(        
        ("",{"fields": 
        ( 
            ('last_name',), ('income',),
),
            }
            ), 
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we inspect the admin page, we can see it is the property `float:left` that is causing the labels to go the left as they do.

We can actually define custom classes for each fieldset in your admin, and you can include custom css files for each admin page. The following adds the class `stack_labels` to your fieldset, and adds a file called `custom_admin_css.css` (stored in your static directory) into the head of your admin page.

```
class ApplicationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        css = {
        'all': ('static/your_app/custom_admin_css.css',),
    }

    form = ApplicationAdminForm
    list_display = ['last_name', 'income']

    fieldsets=(        
        ("",{
            "fields": ( 
                ('last_name',), ('income',),
            ),
            "classes": ("stack_labels",)
        }
        ), 
    )
```

So now, all we need to do is write some CSS:

```
.stack_labels label {
    float:initial;
}
```

This will fix things for you :)